# Launch Modeless Dialog Box with styled XML source file

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dialog

The main question is, can I launch a modeless dialog box from an HTML page, with the ShowModelessDialog function, and have the source be a styled XML file?

I'm aware that modeless boxes only work in IE, and am okay with that - most of our customers will be on IE 6, 7, or 8 (long story, and I have no control over it).  I'll run a test and open a regular child window if they're running a non-IE browser, and those unfortunates will just have to deal with it dropping behind the parent. I'm also aware that JQuery and other JS libraries offer draggable divs. This isn't a good solution for us.

When I launch the XML file as a regular child window, it communicates with the linked XSL file, which in turn uses linked JS and CSS files.  I haven't gotten to the part where I actually process the XML yet - I just display a default xsl-text to make sure everything is talking.

When I launch it as a modeless dialog box, it is the correct size as outlined in the parent HTML, but it has no content, no styling, and no scripting.  I've got a properly-sized white box.

Is it even possible to use an XML file as a source for a dialog box?

***CODE***

**Parent HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            showModelessDialog('cc.xml',' ','dialogLeft:20px; dialogTop:20px; dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:150px; resizable:yes');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Just opening this page should launch the dialog</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="transform.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- "sequence" is an optional attribute provided for the developer. It represents the page's location in the lesson.
      It currently is not used by any code -->
<cc>
   <page id="130_4000" sequence="7" content="Closed captioning text goes here."></page>
   <page id="130_4010" sequence="15" content="This lesson page has cc text as well."></page>
   <page id="130_4020" sequence="16" content="And yet another page with cc text..."></page>
</cc>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                <!-- location of javascript and style sheet IN RELATION TO HTML OR XML FILE -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="transform.css"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src=jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="transform.js"></script>
                <title>Closed Caption Window</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p><xsl:text>Testing.</xsl:text></p>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8"
/* CSS Document */
body {
   background-color:#0000ff;
   color:#ffffff;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// JavaScript Document
// This script is currently used only by the closed caption dialog box, transform.xsl

$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("Testing JQuery comms");
});
```

As you can see, I tried to get rid of everything extraneous, just to test the basic file interactions.